# Change body color (overlay) via javascript does not work

Tags: javascript

Trying to get a side-bar navigation. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      transition: background-color .5s;
    }
    
    .sidenav {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .sidenav a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .sidenav .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    #main {
      transition: margin-left .5s;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="main">
      <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
      <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
      <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
    </div>
    
    <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    }
    
    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    </script>
       
    </body>
    </html>
```

It works nice. The sidebar apperas. But something is wrong the body backgrund color change (script below).

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
```

Script seems to work. I can change the style.width element and the result is on the page.

What i tried:

- Give body a background color. normale state body background color is not definied.
- put script direct in .html file
- put script external
- gave body an ID called "body" and with this -> document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "red";

No errors in console. Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";` doesn't work? or something else? That line works fine in your example

Comment: Sorry for confisng. Yes. The line document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"; does not work

Comment: But as you can see, running the code above works fine. What browser does it not work for you? or all browsers?

Comment: Yeah i see. Maybe wrong section for this question. I can see that style="background-color: #000000;" is added to body. but it does not change. I think BS4 says no

Comment: You will have to figure where the black is getting set. Maybe change your code so it adds a simple colour and see if it works. You have lost me on the BS4 part

Comment: will update this post when i found the solution. BS4 -> Bootstrap 4.
I think some default CSS is overtaking the rule.